# Exposing API built on Laravel to Gearman job

Tags: php, curl, laravel, gearman, worker

I have implemented a Gearman server on the same machine as my webserver, in order to do some background video processing for a platform I'm working on (built on Laravel). So far, everything works well except for the grand finale, when the Gearman worker should notify the platform processing is complete.

I've created an API endpoint, as a route in Laravel without any form of authentification (for the moment). This endpoint is sent to the job as a parameter, which access it using cURL after processing the video. However, the `curl_exec()` call fails without setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. Still, setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` will fail as well, because `open_basedir` restrictions are in place. It seems that cURL does not care that the calling script is located in a folder under a valid `open_basedir` location... it fails out of principle.

Could you suggest a way to rework this without removing `open_basedir` restrictions? Or maybe a different way of signaling processing is complete. I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: Did you consider onComplete hook? [GearmanClient::setCompleteCallback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.setcompletecallback.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could use is this package

https://github.com/pafelin/laravel-gearman

follow the instructions from the README file and basically there will be no difference if you use the sync driver or the beanstalk driver or the gearman. This package adds full support for gearman to Laravel4.x